# How to deduce reason for server being unaccessible?

Tags: server

I am still super bad reading logs, so I am not sure what was the reason for server being unaccessible (I had to hardware reset it, so I was able to connect even via SSH).
Here is my syslog: https://codeshare.io/alnq8D
And here is my kern.log: https://codeshare.io/2jd7KP

As you can see from error on startup the issue happened somewhere BEFORE:
May 15 23:31:52 Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal kernel
And this
May 15 18:19:25 Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal kernel

Please UBuntu gurus show me the way!

Comment: I see no useful clues in the log. Many --but not all-- kernel crashes manage to output something, but there's nothing there for these two crashes. If it happens frequently, then start looking for a hardware cause like bad RAM of a dying power supply.,

Comment: @user535733 thank you for at least confirming my suspicion. Can you recommend free monitoring software? That will log whatever may cause stuff like that (be it CPU, RAM, hard disk or network) ?

Comment: Try the Search box at the top of the page. How to trace hardware faults has been asked and answered several times before.

Comment: In looking at the logs, there are a couple of things that I'd follow up on if I had local access to the logs... but if I had to guess, I'd say that you might have a problem with the power supply. Check that all fans are operational. Look why nginx failed to start. Run a memory test. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.